# Verify a text in the dropdown

Tags: selenium

I am trying to verify if the text is present in the dropdown menu. My assertion shows all the items, but with an error...expected[]but found[]. Please find below my script and the test failure message. Thanks in advance for the help!

My Script:

```
       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#s2id_autogen4 > a.select2-choice > span")).click();;

            ArrayList<String> expectedDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            expectedDropDownItems.add("keysearch");
            expectedDropDownItems.add("short");
            expectedDropDownItems.add("standard");
            expectedDropDownItems.add("to-date");

       Assert.assertEquals(expectedDropDownItems, driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select2-drop']/ul")).getText());
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

java.lang.AssertionError: expected [keysearch

short

standard

to-date] but found [[keysearch, short, standard, to-date]]

HTML:

```
<div style="top: 1973px; left: 261px; width: 500px; display: block;" class="select2-drop select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active" id="select2-drop">   
    <div class="select2-search">       
        <input type="text" class="select2-input" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0">   
    </div>   
    <ul class="select2-results" style="">
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
    <div class="select2-result-label">
        <span class="select2-match"></span>keysearch</div></li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
    <div class="select2-result-label">
        <span class="select2-match"></span>short</div></li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
    <div class="select2-result-label">
        <span class="select2-match"></span>standard</div></li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" style="">
    <div class="select2-result-label">
        <span class="select2-match"></span>to-date</div></li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are comparing an `ArrayList<String>` to a `String`, are you aware of that?

Comment: Ummmmm, can you please show me the right way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: This dropdown, you are comparing to, can you add the HTML snippet of it please ?

Comment: @Subh I have added HTML above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is,

**1- First get all the elements of the dropdown.

2- Put it in a List

3- Iterate over the list, get texts of each element and then put it in a new ArrayList of Strings.

4- Assert using this ArrayList and the Original ArrayList of items.**

Below code will help you out:

```
//Putting actual items in the Arraylist of expectedDropDownItems 
ArrayList<String> expectedDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();
expectedDropDownItems.add("keysearch");
expectedDropDownItems.add("short");
expectedDropDownItems.add("standard");
expectedDropDownItems.add("to-date");

//Iterating over expected items and printing        
System.out.println("\n--- Expected Items");
for(int i=0;i<expectedDropDownItems.size();i++)
    System.out.println(expectedDropDownItems.get(i));

System.out.println("\n");

ArrayList<String> actualDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();

//Getting the list of all items in dropdown     
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='select2-result-label']"));
//Iterating over the list of dropdown, getting text of each element and adding the text to the Arraylist of actualDropDownItems 
for(WebElement element : elements){
    System.out.println("Adding element: "+ element.getText());
    actualDropDownItems.add(element.getText());
}

//Iterating over actual items and printing      
System.out.println("\n--- Actual Items");
for(int i=0;i<actualDropDownItems.size();i++)
    System.out.println(actualDropDownItems.get(i));

//Asserting the ArrayLists if they are equal or not     
Assert.assertEquals(expectedDropDownItems, actualDropDownItems);
System.out.println("Asserted text match");
```

Comment: I am getting this message: java.lang.AssertionError: null: lists don't have the same size expected [0] but found [4]
Thanks!

Comment: In the code that you provided above, all I had to change the xpath to "//*[@id='select2-drop']/ul/li" for Getting the list elements, and it worked :). You did it "again". Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

---

According to assertion i can suppose and suggest to do next on attempt to fix your problem (p.s. i'm not good at java, but according my exp in C#):
1. Try to print data returned from driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select2-drop']/ul")).getText() code and make sure that this data really equals to your data from arrayList.
2. If data seem equal, try another assertion methods (such as Assert.That(object, matcher) (e.g. in C# in could be Assert.That(new[]{1}, Is.EquivalentTo(new[]{1}));), Assert.arrayEquals etc)

If both arrays are equal and asserts not help, please provide sample of html and we will try to solve that problem in other way.

Comment: I have added HTML above. Thanks!